# use withStyles with named export React Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This component is not a default export component.  I'm trying to set some styles for it but not sure how to wrap this in an HOC here.  So right now, it doesn't know what `classes` is.

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = (theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    control: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
    },
});

export class FeaturedCompanyGroup extends Component<{ formattedFeaturedCompanies: Array<JSX.Element> }> {
    render() {
        const { formattedFeaturedCompanies } = this.props;
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <Grid alignItems="center" className={classes.root} container direction="row">
                { formattedFeaturedCompanies }
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: *Don't* export the unwrapped class, `export const Whatever = withStyles(ClassName)`.

Comment: have you defined `styles` type definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = (theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    control: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
    },
});

 class FeaturedCompanyGroup extends Component<{ formattedFeaturedCompanies: Array<JSX.Element> }> {
    render() {
        const { formattedFeaturedCompanies } = this.props;
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <Grid alignItems="center" className={classes.root} container direction="row">
                { formattedFeaturedCompanies }
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

export const withFeaturedCompanyGroup = withStyles(styles)(FeaturedCompanyGroup);
```

Comment: err, yea I was thinking about that... I hate HOCs

Comment: haha.. then you might consider hooks. Material has all support for that as well

Comment: yea I'd have to refactor the entire component, maybe later